# How to check if one list starts with another?

Tags: python, list, startswith

If I have two lists in Python, `[0, 1]` and `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, how do I check if the first list starts with the second?

I know how to do this with strings, just use the `startswith` method. But apparently you can't do that for lists.

Is there a one-liner that does what I described?

Comment: Suppose you had code that could make a sub-list of the longer list, taking only as many elements as are in the shorter list. Do you know how to write that code? Can you think of a way to use that result to solve the problem?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I suppose.

Comment: Suppose you had code that can pair up elements from the lists in a loop, and code that could compare one element at a time. If you had those pieces, could you use them to solve the problem? Do you know how to write those pieces?

Comment: There are many other possible approaches. On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try *something*, and then we can help you figure out what went wrong. You are also expected to demonstrate that you made some effort to find a solution (for example, by showing specific things you searched for, and explaining specifically why they were unable to help you solve the problem).

Comment: I'd use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) if I were you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you meant

```
if the list x starts with the list y
>>> x[0:len(y)] == y 
True
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> y
[0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate them parallelly and check that the corresponding values are equal. You can create a generator expression for the equality iterating using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), along with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```py
>>> a = [0, 1]
>>> b = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> all(i==j for i,j in zip(a,b))
True
```

This works because `zip` stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

Comment: Oh...I've been confusing `all` and `any` this entire time.

Comment: `all` and `any` are clear by their name themselves. `all` gives true if each conditions are true  i.e. both `0==0` and `1==1` in this case , `any` gives True if any of the conditions is true, either `0==0` or `1==1`. You can think of them  as Logical AND and Logical OR, `all` is equivalent to logical AND, `any` is equivalent to logical OR.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> a = [0, 1]
>>> b = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> a[:min(len(a), len(b))] == b[:min(len(a), len(b))]
True
```